# 'this' is undefined in Angular, XML2JS

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, xml2js

```
export class ServerComponent {
servers:string[];
getString:any;

serversJSON:any;
    constructor() {
      }
    ngOnInit() {
        console.log("ngOnInit");   
         this.getXmlService.getData().subscribe((getString) => 
        {
          xml2js.parseString(getString, function (err, result) {
            this.serverJSON = result; // This doesn't work
            console.log(result);      // This works
            });
        });
      }
}
```

In this code, the indicated line does not seem to be able to access `this`. Console logging shows an `undefined`.
`result` gives me a correct and formatted JSON, but when I attempt to take the `result` variable and set it in the `this.serverJSON`, it throws an error `Cannot set property 'serversJSON' of undefined`.
I want to take the value held in result and put it in `serversJSON`.
How can this be achieved and why is `this` not available?

Comment: And this is a difference between normal function and arrow function. :) Just wonder how come you used arrow first and then switch to function expression?

Comment: I see `=>` is already used in your code. I assume you have no idea what it does? If so recommend to read "Arrow functions".

Comment: @dfsq, you're correct. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Is there advantage to not using the Arrow function?

Comment: @vc669 You could do it with `function` too, but in this case there is no point in not using arrow function. Use `(err, result) => { `.

Comment: It works perfectly with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are losing the context of `this` within your callback function.

Use a fat-arrow function (which preserves `this`) instead.

```
xml2js.parseString(getString, (err, result) => {
  this.serverJSON = result;
});
```